# Binding Dropdownlist in Jquery from wcf by passing data

Tags: wcf, jquery

I am trying to bind dropdownlist in JQuery by passing data to WCF.

JQuery Code is:

```
    function PopulateCity()
    {        
    var StateID = { 'stateId': $("[id$=ddlState]").val() };        
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(StateID);        
    $('[id$=ddlCity]').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');        
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost:49583/Service1.svc/PopulateCities',
                data: jsondata,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    BindCity(data,'ddlCity');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
    }

function BindCity(list, control) {    
         $.each(list, function (value, text) {            
            $("select[id$=" + control + "]").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
 }
```

and WCF Code is:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<CityDetails> PopulateCities(int stateId);
```

implemented interface is:

```
List<CityDetails> IService1.PopulateCities(int stateId) {

            List<CityDetails> arrCity = new List<CityDetails>();
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            //String strQuery = "select ID, CityName from Cities where CountryID=@CountryID";
            String strSP = "Car_GetSubMasterDetails";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterID", stateId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", "City");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Culture", "en-US");
                    cmd.CommandText = strSP;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        arrCity.Add(new CityDetails() { Value = sdr["ID"].ToString(), Text = sdr["CityName_en_US"].ToString() });
                       // list.Add(new ListItem(
                       //sdr["CityName_en_US"].ToString(),
                       //sdr["ID"].ToString()
                       // ));
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return arrCity;                    
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't understand where I am wrong.It's neither binding dropdownlist nor showing any error.Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean not showing any error? Have you checked the browsers error console?

Comment: Yes, I have checked but I didn't get any error.Please check my code and suggest me if there is any error in it. I have failed to find out the solution.

Comment: In the given example,I am trying to bind dropdownlist which filled by passing data to wcf service which return data in form of json.Code executed successfully but failed to bind dropdownlist.

Comment: is the service firing?? did you try debugging?